# Is there a matplotlib.pyplot function to draw two columns plot?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-visualization

I'm experimenting with data visualization.

I've got the following dataframe:

```
one = {'year' : [2010,2011,2012,2010],
      'value' : [10,10,20,30],
      'model' : ['one', 'one', 'one', 'two']}
df = pd.DataFrame(one)
df
```

I'd like to plot a line showing the increasing value of model one.
I've tried this:

```
df.set_index('model').loc['one'].plot()
```

[image: My plot]

But it doesn't show the appropriate plot which is `df.set_index('model').loc['one']` versus `df['year']` 
Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC:

try:

```
df.pivot('model','year','value').plot()
```

OR

```
#import seaborn as sns
sns.relplot(kind='line',x='model',y='value',data=df,hue='year')
```

output:

[image]

Comment: It works! Is there any way I could add the appropriate years to the x label?

Comment: @girolamo years are mentioned in the legend of the graph!!...since there are nan's in your dataset so that's why only year 2010 is plotting